# Save images from google sheets list of urls to google drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of images urls in a sheet. I am trying to

1 - downlod the images to google drive folder

2 - list the urls of the newly saved images in a new column.

I managed to find a solution to download the images ( Step 1 )  here https://youtu.be/6cgMbq_t5V0

Now I only need to add a new column and list the google drive sharable url front of each original image url. Is there a way to do that using google apps script?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### Save image urls in a folder

```
function saveImagesInDrive() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const startrow = 2;//edit as necessary
  const column = 1;//edit as necessary
  const urls = sh.getRange(startrow,column,sh.getLastRow() - startrow + 1).getValues().flat();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  let o = urls.map((u,i)=>{
    let b = UrlFetchApp.fetch(u).getBlob();
    let f = folder.createFile(b);
    f.setName(`file-${i}`);
    return [f.getUrl()];
  });
  sh.getRange(startrow, column + 1, o.length).setValues(o);//adding url to column + 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to list the newly saved urls in a second column in the sheet?